# What are some great examples of wordsmanship in published literature?

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-writing

David L. Goodstein begins his book on statistical mechanics, ''States of Matter'', with the following introduction:

> "Ludwig Boltzmann, who spent much of his life studying statistical mechanics, died in 1906, by his own hand. Paul Ehrenfest, carrying on the work, died similarly in 1933. Now it is our turn to study statistical mechanics. Perhaps it will be wise to approach the subject cautiously."

What are some other examples of amusing wordsmanship that appear in mathematical literature?

Comment: please don't use the word "amusing" in connection with the tragedy of someone taking their own life.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker The word "amusing" here describes the wording of the author, not anybody's tragedy. But in the future perhaps it would be wise to approach the subject of wordings cautiously.